# How to use Google Material Symbols on Expo React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I've been searching the internet for a solution to use Google Material Symbols on my Expo React Native project. But what I got is only Material Icons, I need Material Symbols

And I know I can just download the Material Symbols icon from their site, but I was hoping of something like import so the quality of the icons is clear

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you with my Expo React Native project and I ended up using this [material-symbols](https://github.com/marella/material-symbols) library and just installed one of the svg packages.

Ran: `npm install @material-symbols/svg-500@latest`

Then imported it:

```
import ReleaseAlertOutlined from '@material-symbols/svg-500/outlined/release_alert.svg'
```

This should save you from having to manually download icons into an assets folder and instead just pull using the library.